# Reconcile definitions of divergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone help me reconcile these two definitions of a divergent sequence.

Starting with the definition of a convergent sequence:

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge M$,  $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$

If I negate that definition I get:

$\neg$ ($\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge M$, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$)

= $\exists \epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $\forall M \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \ge M$ such that  $|x_n - x| \ge \epsilon_0$

How can I get that negation to reconcile with this definition of a divergent sequence:

$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge N, x_n \gt M$

I think in the second definition the M is supposed to be the proposed limit, which is simply x in the first definition, but I can't seem to mentally get my head around how these two statements are the same. I.e., is there a to make all the variables represent the same thing and see them side by side and have it make sense?

Comment: Note that your first statement only speaks of "convergent sequences which converge specifically to $x$".  Negating those would include all the convergent sequences with a limit other than $x$.

Comment: Also, you definition of "divergent" is extremely limited.  It doesn't include $\{-n\}$, for instance, nor does it include $\{(-1)^n\}$.

Comment: The definition of "convergent" (instead of "convergent to $x$") requires putting an $\exists x \in R$ at the front (where $R$ is whatever space this convergence is in). Thus, "divergent" (whose definition is just "not convergent", and thus the full expression you are seeking is a theorem, not a definition itself) will have a $\forall x\in R$ preceding what you stated. And of course your other statement is "diverges to $\infty$", not just "diverges".

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

$\exists \epsilon_0 > 0,$ such that $\forall M \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n \ge M$, such that  $|x_n - x| \ge \epsilon_0$

means that: *The sequence $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $x$.* However, if a sequence does not converge to a specified $x$, it does not necessarily diverge. It could for example converge to an $x'\ne x$.

On the other hand:

$\forall M \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge N, x_n \gt M$

Means: *The sequence $\{x_n\}$ tends to infinity.*

If a sequence diverges it does not necessarily tend to infinity. For example $x_n=(-1)^nn$.